# DropdownList value is getting null in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Account account, FormCollection fc)
{   
    using (accountgoEntities entities = new accountgoEntities())
    {
        entities.Account.Add(account);
        entities.SaveChanges();
        int id = account.Id;
    }

    //return View(Account);
    return  RedirectToAction("Account_details");
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <strong class="strong">company name  </strong>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("CompanyName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CompanyName, "chose", new { @class = "form-control" })

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: after submitting the form companyId = null

Comment: I want you to go and re-read your question two or three times and think really hard about whether it contains any information which could possibly help somebody figure out what is wrong or what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in the comment that:

> after submitting the form companyId = null

This is actually becuase your drop down select input field name is `CompanyName` instead of `CompanyId`

So name it `CompanyId` as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <strong class="strong">Company Name</strong>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("CompanyId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CompanyName, "Select Company", new { @class = "form-control" })

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Now `CompanyId` will have a value on post.